# inequality about the taylor error estimation of e^x

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

here's the problem: For all polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$ find a symmetric interval about $0$ for which the inequality below holds:
\begin{equation}
|e^x-(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})| \le |e^x-(ax^2+bx+c)|
\end{equation}
I tried substituting the left side with $\frac{e^xx^3}{6}$ using taylor polynomial remainder but I don't know how to continue. just pay attention that you should find that interval for all such polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$ just proving that it exists is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the points where 0 <= lhs <= rhs, or 0 <= lhs <= -rhs, or 0 >= lsh >= rhs, or 0 >= lhs >= -rhs (removing the absolute values). I’d first see where e^x - 1 - x - x^2/2 changes its sign, and then you just compare polynomials. Mostly.